# Up to parent folder for 403

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-403, directory-structure

How to up to parent folder for my `htaccess` below:

The `htaccess` file is on folder include. Structure:

```
-parentfolder
 404.html
  -include
   .htaccess
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Deny from all
ErrorDocument 403 /parentfolder/403
```

Now I want it to up to parent folder:

```
/../parentfolder/403
```

But still not working.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "I want it to up to parent folder" mean? "Up" is not a verb.

Comment: Hi, I mean up to parentfolder.

Answer (score 0):

The .htacces must be in parentfolder

Comment: I have another .htaccess on that parentfolder